# execve() failing to launch program in C

Tags: c, linux, assembly, execute, execve

I am trying to spawn a new process using `execve()` from `unistd.h` on Linux. I have tried passing it the following parameters `execve("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", NULL);` but get no result. I do not get an error either, the program just exits. Is there a reason why this is happening? I have tried launching it as root and regular user. The reason I need to use `execve()` is because I am trying to get it to work in an assembly call like so

```
program: db "/bin/ls",0

mov eax, 0xb
mov ebx, program
mov ecx, program
mov edx, 0
int 0x80
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The arguments that you're passing to `execve` are wrong. Both the second and third *must* be an array of char pointers with a NULL sentinel value, not a single pointer.

In other words, something like:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main (void) {
    char * const argv[] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};
    char * const envp[] = {NULL};
    int rc = execve ("/bin/ls", argv, envp);
    return rc;
}
```

When I run that, I do indeed get a list of the files in the current directory.

Comment: Gotcha, `man execve` said an array, I assumed just a normal string would do. Lesson learned, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) pages,

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

So the problem in your case is that you haven't passed the 2nd and the 3rd argument correctly.

```
/* execve.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *newargv[] = { NULL, "hello", "world", NULL };
    char *newenviron[] = { NULL };


newargv[0] = argv[1];

execve(argv[1], newargv, newenviron);


}
//This is a over-simplified version of the example in the man page
```

Run this as:

```
$ cc execve.c -o execve
$ ./execve ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [`man execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) again. You are passing the wrong arguments to it. Pay particular attention to what the second argument should be.

Also, running your program under `strace` could be illuminating.

Comment: `strace` gives me `-1 EFAULT (Bad address)`, I have re-read the man page on it, but I am still confused. Am I passing the second argument incorrectly? (the process arguments)