# execve() has a weird behavior depending on the state of an unused variable

Tags: c, unix, null, ls, execve

I've just recently been exploring the execve() system function. This code might not make much sense but that's not the main focus of this question. (I've managed to make it work correctly since, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469818/execve-failing-to-launch-program-in-c) thread).

I've come across a really weird behavior and wanted either an explanation or a confirmation that something like this should not happen.

The "bugged" code is this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return (ERROR_CODE);
    char *test[] = { argv[1] };
    char *a[] = { NULL };

    execve(argv[1], test, env);
    return (SUCCESS_CODE);
}
```

Compiling and executing it with an argument will correctly execute that function, in my case:

```
$> gcc main.c
$> ./a.out "/bin/ls"
```

This would work like the ls function would.
Now remove/comment this line:

```
char *a[] = { NULL };
```

This variable is clearly not used and completely useless.
Do the same steps once again and for some reason, it doesn't output anything, this one random variable breaks the code for me. (I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.8 and gcc 9.3.0).

If you need any more information about my OS or anything, feel free to ask.

PS: I think I understand the way the code is trying to work this out but It makes no sense to me.

```
$> man execve

main(int argc, char *argv[])
char *newargv[] = { NULL, "hello", "world", NULL };
...
execve(argv[1], newargv, newenviron);
```

The manual example null-terminates "newargv", my idea is that somehow, somewhere, the compiler decided to fuse together my variables "test" and "a", to null-terminate "test"?

Comment: [man execve](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html): "The argv array must be terminated
       by a NULL pointer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you're *accidentally* seeing that "fusing" since you're not correctly terminating `argv` with a  `NULL` and the memory layout happens to be in your favor. If you were less lucky, you'd get garbage in there, or a segfault.

Quoth the manpage ([Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [Darwin](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/execve.2.html)), emphasis mine,

> The argument `argv` is a pointer to a **null-terminated array** of character pointers to null-terminated character strings.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return (ERROR_CODE);
    char *test[] = { argv[1], NULL };

    execve(argv[1], test, env);
    return (SUCCESS_CODE);
}
```

would be the correct invocation.